# Dynamics CRM 2011 email a group/distribution list

Tags: email, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a custom entity within MS CRM 2011 called 'Transport Company' and within it I have records of all the Transport companies we use.

If i want to send out an email to them all I can create an email and select via the TO loopkup all the 'Transport Company' records one by one.

However, I want to also have the option of just selecting a group that has all the appropriate records within it, e.g Transport Companies England, Transport Companies Germany etc

I don't get the option to add records from a view to a Quick Campaign as has been suggested online. Has anyone any guidance on how to go about this?

Comment: Has anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have set the "Sending email (if an email field does not exist, one will be created)" checkbox in the Transport Company entity to true (in the communicaiton & collaboration section).

1. Create a custom view on the Transport Company entity to filter to
   each of the groups. (Transport Companies England, Transport
   Companies Germany... etc).
2. Navigate to Sales -> Activities and create a new Email
3. In the Bcc (or To) field, click on the search button. Scroll to the
   end and click "Look up more records".
4. In the "Look For" box, select "Transport Company" and in the "Look
   In" box, select the target view (Transport Companies England,
   Transport Companies Germany... etc). Select all entries and click
   the "Select" button. Click the "Add" button.

you should now see all of the targeted transport companies in the Bcc (or to) field.

This email will be sent to all selected "Transport Companies" where the "email address" field has been filled in.

Note: the "Regarding" field of the email will not be filled in.